# Change order of rows accomplishing a condition

Tags: r

Imagine I have this dataframe:

```
A    B    C    D
1    2    3    4
5    7    6    8
9    10   11   12
13   15   14   16
```

How can I reorder rows of columns `B` and `C` just when `B` is higher than `C`?

My desired output would be:

```
A   B    C   D
1   2    3   4
5   6    7   8
9   10   11  12
13  14   15  16
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmin` and `pmax` :

```
transform(df, B = pmin(B, C), C = pmax(B, C))

#   A  B  C  D
#1  1  2  3  4
#2  5  6  7  8
#3  9 10 11 12
#4 13 14 15 16
```

Or with `ifelse` :

```
transform(df, B = ifelse(B > C, C, B), C = ifelse(C > B, C, B))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply()`:

```
df[c("B", "C")] <- t(apply(df[c("B", "C")], 1, sort))

df
   A  B  C  D
1  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8
3  9 10 11 12
4 13 14 15 16
```

Answer (score 0):

WE can also do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(B = pmin(B, C), C = pmax(B, C))
```